# MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

For an iOS application doing a bulk insert/update/delete in core data usihg MagicalRecord: Will using saveWithBlockAndWait perform any batch save to persistent store ? According to Apple's recommendations the save operation must be done in batches (say saving 50 or 100 records to disk) so as to avoid memory rise. Do have to call

```
[lcoalContext save:nil];
```

at some regular intervals inside saveWithBlockAndWait ? Here lcoalContext is an instance of NSManagedObjectContext available from saveWithBlockAndWait method.

Comment: You should always check the error.  Passing `nil` there is asking for trouble.  Print it out to `NSLog()` if nothing else.

Comment: If you're using MagicalRecord and are compiling a DEBUG build, all Core Data errors are captured and logged for you automatically unless you explicitly disable them.

Comment: thanks for your comment but my question is not related to error handling. I am concerned with batch saving using saveWithBlockAndWait in batches.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion for your needs:

1. Create a separate NSManageObjectContext for the whole insert/update/delete process.
2. Create/update/delete your entities using this context. (Remember, that each MR service has an implementation you to be able to specify the context the operation to be performed into).
3. You have to create a counter to observe when should the context be saved.
4. Call save on the given context periodically.

I wrote a short example directly for you:

```
- (void) batchProcessToCreate1000Objects{
    //This will create a separated context which is the child of the main context. You can use MR_newPrivateQueueContext instead of this if you would like to use a fully separated context (it won't merge the changes into the main context).
    NSManagedObjectContext* localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    for (int counterToObservWhenToSave = 0; counterToObservWhenToSave < 1000; counterToObservWhenToSave++) {
        YourManagedObject* objectToInsert = [NSManagedObject MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        objectToInsert.name = @"Chris P. Backon";
        objectToInsert.isStackOverFlowExample = @YES;
        if (counterToObservWhenToSave > 0 && (counterToObservWhenToSave % 50 == 0)) {
            [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        }
    }

}
```

And, just a note:
You should never call save: in a saveWithBlockAndWait function. This function will save automatically (if you made any CD changes inside the block).

Good luck for coding!